# Get Date Object with UTC instead of local time zone in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, web, dynamics-crm

I am uploading a date time to a field on a dynamics form, and the form needs to receive a UTC date time. If I do something like this:

```
new Date(new Date().toISOString())
```

If i console.log the date it shows as: `Fri Dec 18 2020 14:27:39 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)`

I want the object to print as the UTC time with UTC specified as the time zone, otherwise the form (expecting a date object) keeps uploading as the EST time.

Comment: Do you mean something like `new Date().toUTCString()`?

Answer (score 0):

Use Date.UTC

const utcDate1 = new Date(Date.UTC(96, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5));

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC)

Comment: if you console.log that utcDate1 object, it still renders it in the local time

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: As another user mentioned, you must use [Date.UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC).

```js
var date = new Date(Date())

var utcDate = date.toUTCString();

console.log(utcDate)
```

Comment: this just gets me a string of the day of the month in UTC (so for today it would be 18) ... look at the output of your snippet, clearly not what i am looking for although i do appreciate you taking time out of your day to try

Comment: Apologies, please see my updated snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Date objects are just an offset in milliseconds from the ECMAScript epoch, 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. They do not have a timezone. When you stringify the object you get a timestamp that depends on the method used.

Most methods (e.g. *toString*) use the host settings for timezone and offset and produce timestamps based on those settings.

If you want an ISO 8601 compliant string with zero offset, the use [*toISOString*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) or [*toUTCString*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString) depending on the format you want:

```js
let d = new Date();
console.log(`local time : ${d.toString()}`);
console.log(`toISOString: ${d.toISOString()}`);
console.log(`toUTCString: ${d.toUTCString()}`);
```

See [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C1732.5391).

In your code, the expression:

```
new Date(new Date().toISOString())
```

firstly creates a Date object for the current moment in time, then generates a timestamp per the *toISOString* method. That is then parsed back into a Date object, so the result is identical to:

```
new Date();
```